# PHP save console output

Tags: php, exec, output

Im trying to save all the output lines from a console to a file the code is not working because what it currently does is

Get the last line from console and write it on the file, and also the file isnt updated until I close the process the console is running-

```
    $start = exec("cd /ot/forgottenserver && ./tfs", $output);

    $file = fopen("/var/www/public/stream.html", "a+");

    while ($start) 
    {
    fwrite($file, $start."\n");
    }

    fclose($file);
```

I need to write everytime I get a new line from the console and also update the file while the process is executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `popen` instead of `exec`. As opposed to `exec` (which executes the command and returns only *after* the process finished), `popen` returns a pointer to that process which you can use in order to read the output.

```php
$h = popen('cd /ot/forgottenserver && ./tfs', 'r');

if ($h) {
    while (!feof($h)) {
        $buf = fread($h, 1024);

        $fileHandle = fopen("/var/www/public/stream.html", "a+");

        if ($fileHandle) {
            fwrite($fileHandle, $buf);
            fclose($fileHandle);
        }
    }

    pclose($h);
}
```